# Does incapsula support websockets?

Tags: incapsula

I have an email from Incapsula explaining they don't support websockets. I find this strange to say the least, and their support rep just copy pasted a wikipedia article (they don't even seem to know what it is).

I'm getting all sort of 'malformed' requests when I try to run websockets with their service, though.

Comment: since you didn't get any answer till now, I'll give you tip... Test!

Comment: Tested - incapsula indeed does not support websockets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that, given

- An email saying websockets aren't supported
- Errors when you try to use websockets

that Incapsula doesn't support websockets. Whatever it is you're trying to do, you'll need to do it a different way (or change CDNs).

Comment: I've just tried without Incapsula, and it worked a treat. Incapsula doesn't support websockets, meaning you may be able to run long polling type tricks through socketIO but that's about it. Very disappointing!

Answer (score 7):

Sorry to revive an old topic, but - in the interest of keeping things up-to-date - Incapsula does now supports websockets.

https://incapsula.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202579260-Websocket-support-with-Incapsula

Comment: Thank you! I just switched away from CloudFlare for this.